# Bamboo SSH Task to start Selenium Grid

Tags: windows-10, ssh, selenium, bamboo

I am using Atlassian Bamboo version 6.5.0 (build 60509 - 20 Apr 18). On a remote computer I have Selenium grid running (both hub and node).

My current Bamboo job sends the tests to the remote server and runs the tests on the grid successfully. I want Bamboo to start the grid itself - so I use an SSH task to send the command

```
javaw -jar path-to-standalone.jar -role hub -port 4444
```

Which successfully starts the hub - but this task never returns so the next stage which starts the tests never executes! I have tried redirecting both `stderr` and `stdout` for the SSH task but nothing seems to work.

How can I start the remote Selenium grid from Bamboo using the SSH task?

**EDIT**
I have tried the approaches mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483173/atlassian-bamboo-ssh-task-for-spring-boot but none of them work. I assume the problem I am having is related to the SSH output.